# reliable scripting way of obtaining UUID of boot partition

Tags: scripting, boot, uuid

I want to script a somewhat automated method for editing `/etc/default/grub` and appending `fips=1 boot=UUID=????` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=`

coincidentally `/etc/fstab` contains `UUID=12345blabla  /boot  xfs defaults 0 0`.  But in the event mount types are not by UUID in /etc/fstab what is a reliable way of deducing the UUID of the boot partition on linux [any RHEL/Centos 7.6 system or later]?

Answer (score 3):

I'll start off by saying that this doesn't address the part of your question about automated modification of `/etc/default/grub`, but I suspect that shouldn't really be needed.

The UUID should be static unless you're reformatting the partition.  Assuming you know the underlying device, you look at `/dev/disk/by-uuid`, and see something like:

```
$ ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid
... 9577f213-665a-427b-aa45-8927b177224e -> ../../sda1
...
```

So you just need to find the corresponding one for the device that is your boot partition.

There's also the `blkid` command:

```
$ blkid /dev/sda1
/dev/sda1: UUID="9577f213-665a-427b-aa45-8927b177224e" ...
```

Are you looking at a situation where the UUID changes for some reason?

Comment: UUID should never change.  I guess it's a matter of expecting to parse output of `mount` command and find which `dev` is just `/boot` and pulling that UUID, and NOT for `/boot/efi`.  Or maybe parse `/etc/fstab`

Comment: Do the commands that I suggested above not work for you?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for the UUID of the device mounted as `/boot` on a running system, a clean way is `findmnt` from `util-linux`:

```
$ findmnt --output=UUID --noheadings --target=/boot 
2b8c6b62-0f68-47d1-a5e7-3e56acce98ac
```

With these self-explanatory options it outputs the UUID only. It also saves you the hassle of figuring out which device is the relevant one.

If you are just looking for the UUID of a device you know of, regardless of whether it is mounted or not, you can use `blkid`, as mentioned in [Andy Dalton's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/507777/315749):

```
$ sudo blkid -s UUID -o value /dev/vda1 
2b8c6b62-0f68-47d1-a5e7-3e56acce98ac
```

The `-s tag` and `-o format` options restrict the output to the value of the UUID tag only.

You can then append the UUID to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` with a command as:

```bsh
sed -i.bkp 's/^\([[:blank:]]*GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=".*\)\(".*\)$/\1 fips=1 boot=UUID='"$newuuid"'\2/' /etc/default/grub
```

Which assumes the `-i` option's syntax of GNU `sed`: it will edit the file in-place, also creating a `grub.bkp` backup file.
Note that we are not checking if a `boot` command line parameter is already there; we are just appending `fips=1`*`newuuid`* before the second `"`, thus assuming your current command line is enclosed in double quotes and does not contain any double quote.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's find the boot partition with

```
fdisk -l | grep '^/dev/[a-z]*[0-9]' | awk '$2 == "*"'
```

Then feed its output, as kindly suggested by [Andy Dalton](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/90691/andy-dalton) above,  to [blkid](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/blkid.8.html)

```
fdisk -l | grep '^/dev/[a-z]*[0-9]' | awk '$2 == "*"' | blkid $1
```